# Sentrifugo, 500 HTTP Error

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed the latest version of Sentrifugo on AWS ( EC2 ) - Ubuntu 16.4

Some of the Add and edit pages are returning 500 error. Where can I see logs?

For example .`.../sentrifugo/index.php/wizard/configuresite`  comes back 500 error or 
`.../sentrifugo/index.php/countries/edit`

I have searched a lot, I can't find any straight answer or anything that can be any help.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the PHP version error. Install PHP 5 and you will be fine.
The documentation says PHP 5+, it is incorrect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check directory permission of your project make it 655 on Apache. I did the same and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a missing php module. iconv was missing on the server. I installed it with,

```
yum install ea-php56-php-iconv
```

Please note that it was a cpanel server. So this might not work for everyone

Source: [Sentrifugo 500 HTTP Error](https://vpsfix.com/community/server-administration/sentrifugo-500-http-error-when-try-to-save-site-configuration/)